# CSS or SCSS for cyclic nested style typing

Tags: css, sass

The `css` code below is used to create a nested alternating bullet effect on a `ol` list like so:

[image]

I would like to simplify this `css`:

```css
#meaning ol { list-style-type: circle; }
#meaning ol ol { list-style-type: disc; }
#meaning ol ol ol { list-style-type: circle; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: disc; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: circle; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: disc; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: circle; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: disc; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: circle; }
#meaning ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: disc; }
```

ChatGPT suggested using SCSS, but the code it gave never worked.

The closest I can get is this:

```scss
$max-levels: 10;

#meaning ol {
  list-style-type: circle;

  @for $i from 1 through $max-levels {
    & ol {
      list-style-type: if($i % 2 == 0, circle, disc);
    }
  }
}
```

which translates to this:

```css
#meaning ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
#meaning ol ol {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Close enough. But not quite there yet.

Any suggestions? Any simple solution would do.

Comment: If you need to circle and disc one by one and repeat the ol consistently, then you can use the nth-child(even) & nth-child(odd) pseudo-elements.

Comment: nth-child doesn’t really work in my case because I am concerned with alternating the bullets based on nesting levels. I don’t want disc and circles to alternate within a single sub-list.

Answer (score 1):

Here a SCSS code that works

```
$max-levels: 10;
$styles: disc, circle;

@for $i from 1 through $max-levels {
    $selector: '#meaning';
  
    @for $j from 1 through $i {
      $selector: #{$selector} + ' ol';
    }
  
    #{$selector} {
      list-style: nth($styles, $i % 2 + 1);
    }
  }
```

You can change the $max-levels variable to match the number of ol you want to display !